# Keep MySQL table updated

Tags: mysql

I have a big user data table. This table is slow to select, grouping and ordering data and it's have `date` and `user_id` primary key.
So I want to create a 'copy of big table' but just the latest data of each user.

I tried create the new copy table where just user_id primary key. Then ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

I should use trigger? How the best way to do it?

Comment: Both are viable solutions. Which one to use? Well, that depends on your requirements.

Comment: My requirements is what the best way to create a duplicate of table and maintain data updated

Comment: This is only part of your requirements. Do you have to update the copy real time? Only periodically? Can your system actually support a real time sync? There is no way of answering your question ithout assessing these.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the initial duplicate table as you describe using an INSERT statement selecting all data from the big user data table, using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Then you need either a recurring job to run that same INSERT statement to keep the copy table updated, or a trigger on the source table (the big user data table).

The trigger solution would include a ON INSERT trigger, and if the table is also updated you would also need a ON UPDATE trigger, and if DELETES should be handled you would also need a ON DELETE trigger.

The differences between the solutions is that

- the TRIGGER solution would keep the copy table updated in real time,
  but if there is a lot of activity on the source table then this can
  have performance impacts,
- the recurring job solution would result in a copy table that is not
  always up to date but it can be run during off peak hours.

I have databases where I use both solutions, preferring the trigger version as default, and switching to the recurring job solution if needed.

Example: I use the recurring job solution where I aggregate a days worth of data in a nightly job into an aggregate table since the aggregated data will only be used when I have a full days worth of data.